# Applying GraduatedColorsRenderer based on classification field values in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-notebook

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
data = arcpy.ListFields(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Oakville\Oakville.gdb\Etobicoke")
path = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Oakville\Oakville.gdb\Etobicoke"
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps("Map2")[0]
lyr = m.listLayers('SampleTestingData')[0]
sym = lyr.symbology
flag = True

CSDNames = []
CSDName_minlst = []
CSDName_maxlst = []

# create a list of unique names
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(path, ['EtobicokeDA2_CSDNAME']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] not in CSDNames:
            CSDNames.append(row[0])
# create a list of maximum values for each name
for i in CSDNames:
    maxList = []
    where = """{} = '{}'""".format("EtobicokeDA2_CSDNAME", i)   
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(path, ["EtobicokeData_AVG_Home_Values"], where) as cur2:
        for row2 in cur2:
            if row2[0] not in maxList:
                maxList.append(row2[0])
    maxList.sort()
    CSDName_maxlst.append(int(maxList[-1]))
# create list of minimum values for each name
for i in CSDNames:
    minList = []
    where = """{} = '{}'""".format("EtobicokeDA2_CSDNAME", i)   
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(path, ["EtobicokeData_AVG_Home_Values"], where) as cur2:
        for row2 in cur2:
            if row2[0] not in minList:
                minList.append(row2[0])
    minList.sort()
    minList = [i for i in minList if i != 0]
    CSDName_minlst.append(int(minList[0]))

CSD_ranges = []
# create ranges for each name
for items in range(len(CSDName_minlst)):
    CSD_bin = int((CSDName_maxlst[items]- CSDName_minlst[items])/8)
    bin_1 = CSDName_minlst[items] + CSD_bin
    bin_2 = CSDName_minlst[items] + CSD_bin*2
    bin_3 = CSDName_minlst[items] + CSD_bin*3
    bin_4 = CSDName_minlst[items] + CSD_bin*4
    bin_5 = CSDName_minlst[items] + CSD_bin*5
    bin_6 = CSDName_minlst[items] + CSD_bin*6
    bin_7 = CSDName_minlst[items] + CSD_bin*7
    bin_8 = CSDName_minlst[items] + CSD_bin*8
    CSD_ranges.append([bin_1, bin_2,bin_3, bin_4, bin_5, bin_6, bin_7, bin_8])
```

So I have basically created two lists: one which contains all the unique names and the other contains class break Values for each name.  I was wondering if there is a way to apply symbology based on what the field value is, using a conditional statement. My end goal is to basically use this symbology in the web app and once I filter it to the field value, it would only show me the symbology for that specific field value

Comment: Sounds like you want to be altering the GraduatedColorsRenderer, see [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/graduatedcolorsrenderer-class.htm) for sample code.

Comment: @Hornbydd yes but GraduatedColorsRenderer only applies to the classification field, how do I apply to all the unique names I have in the list?